# How do I get Bluetooth working on Fedora Linux 20?

Tags: software-installation, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to get a HP Office 100 printer to work over Bluetooth from my LinuxFedora 20 PC. I have installed "blueman-0.19-all.tar.gz", I tried to install bluez... but got  "Package bluez-5.18-1.fc20.i686 is already installed. " but "ddnf istall bluez-utils gave "No package bluez-utils available"

I have a link under Applications>Accessories  that is "blueman bluetooth manager" but when I click on it I get an "Error" window that says "No module named bluetooth. Make sure all dependencies are satisfied" Please what do I do to get out of this?

Comment: Are you able to update your system to a current Fedora release? It is extremely likely that whatever issue you have will be resolved and things will just work "out of the box".

Comment: Thank you @mattdm. I am scared of attempting to install Linux 25, I did so on my laptop under the guidance of an "expert", but it now seems terribly slow and unresponsive. So far Linux 20 has struggled on, may be it is time to upgrade, but nothing is as easy as it is promised to be, and that is likely another can of worms waiting to be opened..

Comment: I can't promise perfection, but I _can_ promise that recent versions are easier to use with a lot more polish than the one from 2013. And, that's going to be particularly true with hardware enablement.